# Efficient block-sparse matrix multiplication with Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

Let's say I have a matrix that is sparse, except for blocks along the diagonal (of a fixed size).

`Eigen::SparseMatrix<float> lhs;`

lhs is approximately 2% non-sparse, but may be very large. Then, let's say I have a vector:

`Eigen::MatrixXf rhs = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(SomeSz, 1);`

For the moment, let's assume it's dense.

I want to efficiently compute:

`result.noalias() = lhs * rhs;`

If I was to compile with -O3 -march=native -mtune=native (with Clang), would this produce an optimal result?

Also, what if rhs was sparse:

`Eigen::SparseMatrix<float> rhs; rhs.resize(SomeSz, 1); rhs.reserve(SomeSz/SomeFactor);`

Is:

`result = lhs * rhs;`

still optimal/suboptimal?

I guess what I'm asking is whether or not Eigen will take advantage of the block-sparse structure and only perform the necessary computations.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the dense case for the rhs, if rhs is a vector, then please tell it to Eigen by using `VectorXf`. Then, with Eigen 3.3, you can take advantage of multi-threading by compiling with `-fopenmp` and using a row-major storage of the `lhs`.

In the sparse case, yes Eigen will take into consideration the sparsity of both the lhs and rhs. The complexity will really be `rhs.nonZeros()*average_nnz_per_col_of_lhs`, in contrast to `rhs.size()*average_nnz_per_col_of_lhs` with a dense rhs. So if rhs is really sparse, then it might be worth a try. Only the useful column of lhs will be considered. In this case, better keep the lhs column-major.